# Which mail server can I control from Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, email

I'm looking for a mail server that I can completely control from Python/Django. When I say "completely control", I'm just talking about basic administrative tasks like: (1)setting up new accounts, (2)changing account passwords, (3) setting / changing email forwarding, and perhaps some other basic account settings.

To be specific, my questions are: Which mail server is best for this? Which mail servers have APIs that are most comprehensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've never used lamson, but it's worth taking a look at it.
http://lamsonproject.org/ it seems interesting for several reasons.

but in general, you can easily build a wrapper around any mail server that has commandline tools for configuration, and any mail server that can store users and aliases in a database, would make mail server configuration as easy as doing an inspectdb and adding the correct logic for password creation, etc...